# Multi module maven project is not showing in package structure but as folder structure in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, github, multi-module

I have successfully imported a multi module maven project from GitHub into my eclipse and able to build it successfully.

But the problem is project is being shown in folder structure but not as package structure which is making my day tedious.

Could anybody else faced this issue? Please do suggest your ideas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you share a screenshot of what you mean by folder structure here. And why does this raise any concern?

Answer (score 2):

Check out if the Project view in hierarchical mode would be a better fit for your need.

See [Eclipse 4.5M5](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/):

> The Project Explorer now provides the ability to view the projects in a hierarchical (a.k.a. nested) form.
>   For modular projects, this allows to have your Project Explorer mapping more closely the organization of your modules as they are on the file system.
>   This hierarchical view of projects often makes easier to navigate modular projects.
>
> Hierarchical view of projects can be triggered from the Project Explorer view menu, under the Projects Presentation item.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/images/nested-projects-menu.png]

> Then it makes the folders that are at the same location as a project replaced by the project, and the projects that are nested under other projects will not be shown as root elements.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/images/nested-projects.png]

Comment: Your answer is very descriptive.thanks for that..But I was expecting different answer. In Eclipse project is coming in folder type but not in package structure when it is multi module project. Due to confidential stuff, I am not able to share screen shot

Comment: @Asrinivas Could you edit the screenshot and blur the confidential part?

Comment: I added two screen shots.. I need to have my folder structure as second snap shot.. Thanks

Comment: @Asrinivas What View are you using? Project Explorer? Would the Package Explorer view work better?

Comment: Yes,  my answer is using the hierarchical presentation of the project explorer.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Version: 4.3.0 , I dont see any option like that to change the heirarchical presentation.

Comment: Could you test it with the most eclipse version?

Answer (score 0):

In the folder where you have downloaded the project from git, you will see a .project file. You need to provide **buildspec** and **natures** information in that xml file.

In my case the .project xml file looks like this - 
[image]

Now, make sure that you have provided the **buildspec** and **natures** information as shown in example above.

Once you have made the changes to .project xml file -

1. Right Click the Project >> Refresh
2. Right Click the Project >> Maven  >> Update Project

You will see that the project (source) folder structure is represented in desired format.